# How to handle exception correctly

Tags: ocaml

I am new to OCaml language. I wrote the function for studying numbers multiplication. But I faced with problem in case of exception handling. The deal is when int_of_string function can't convert the user's input to integer it rises exception. I handle this exception but something is wrong. When the user reaches the end of the multiplication table the function is not finished in the case of user's incorrect input.

```ml
let rec mtable x y = 
  Printf.printf " %d * %d = " x y;
  flush stdout;
  let product = (x * y) in
  let u_input = read_line () in
  let t_input = String.trim u_input in 
  match t_input with 
  | "q"  -> Printf.printf "Good bye\n";
  |  another -> 
     let number =
       try (int_of_string another) with
       | Failure(_) -> 
         (Printf.printf "The answer must be a number\n";
          mtable x y;
          product)
     in 
     if (x = 10 && y = 10)  && product = number then
       Printf.printf "You have reached the end of the  table\n"
     else if y = 10 && product = number then
       mtable (x + 1) 1
     else if product = number then
       (Printf.printf "Right answer\n";
        mtable x (y + 1))
     else 
       (Printf.printf "Wrong answer\n";
        mtable x y );;
    
mtable 10 8;;
```

Comment: In case of invalid input, only ask for a single number again, do not run the entire `mtable`. Write a (recursive) helper function to get only a single `number` for that.

Comment: Also you probably want to separate "right answer" from "wrong answer" *before* deciding whether the end of the table was reached, the next `x`, or the next `y` should be asked.

Comment: Tip: check for the base case (end of the recursion) as the first thing in the recursive function, not where you are doing the recursive call. Also use `>=` instead of `=`. Calling `mtable 13 42` should a) terminate and b) not even ask for a number but just print "*you have reached the end*. This will generally lead to safer and simpler code, and more understandable recursion logic.

Comment: @Bergi Thx for your answer. The function call with arguments 13 and 42 is unrealistic cuz this function is "private" in the logic of the program.

Comment: Maybe, but even there I'd rather write safer code, if only to get into the habit :-) The tip was meant as general advice, not just for this particular program.

Comment: @Bergi I will take to consideration your advice

Answer (score 3):

Testing your code:

```
# mtable 10 8;;
 10 * 8 = ty
The answer must be a number
 10 * 8 = 80
Right answer
 10 * 9 = 90
Right answer
 10 * 10 = ert
The answer must be a number
 10 * 10 = rt
The answer must be a number
 10 * 10 = er
The answer must be a number
 10 * 10 = er
The answer must be a number
 10 * 10 = er
The answer must be a number
 10 * 10 = 100
You have reached the end of the  table
You have reached the end of the  table
You have reached the end of the  table
You have reached the end of the  table
You have reached the end of the  table
You have reached the end of the  table
Right answer
 10 * 9 = 90
Right answer
 10 * 10 = 100
You have reached the end of the  table
- : unit = ()
```

I can see how this is not right. I would suggest breaking down your code a bit farther by having a helper function which handles ensuring your input is an int.

Otherwise you're asking one recursive function to handle everything, and that's what's gotten you in trouble.

```
let rec prompt_until_int prmpt =
  print_string prompt;
  match read_int () with
  | n -> n
  | exception Failure _ -> 
    print_endline "Please input an int.";
    prompt_until_int prmpt
```

But if you need an input of `"q"` to indicate that the program should exit, you can raise a `Quit` exception and then handle that separately.

```
exception Quit

let rec prompt_until_int prmpt =
  print_string prmpt;
  let input = 
    String.(
      lowercase_ascii @@ trim @@ read_line () 
    )
  in
  match input with
  | "q" -> raise Quit
  | _ -> 
    (try
       int_of_string input
     with
     | Failure _ -> 
       print_endline "Please enter an int or \"q\" to quit.";
       prompt_until_int prmpt)
```

While breaking things down is a good idea, it isn't essential. We can use a locally scoped function so that we can keep track of the original bounds across our recursion.

Because I've done this, the `10` is no longer hard coded.

```
let mtable x y =
  let rec aux x' y' =
    if y' > x then 
      print_endline "End of table."
    else
      let () = Printf.printf "%d * %d = %!" x' y' in
      let input = String.(lowercase_ascii @@ trim @@ read_line ()) in
      if input = "q" then 
        print_endline "Goodbye!"
      else 
        try
          let n = int_of_string input in
          if n = x' * y' then
            (print_endline "Right answer";
             aux x' (y' + 1))
          else  
            (print_endline "Wrong answer";
             aux x' y')
        with 
        | Failure _ ->
          print_endline "The answer must be a number";
          aux x' y'
  in
  aux x y
```

```
# mtable 4 2;;
4 * 2 = th
The answer must be a number
4 * 2 = 6
Wrong answer
4 * 2 = 8
Right answer
4 * 3 = 12
Right answer
4 * 4 = q
Goodbye!
- : unit = ()
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I used to do the checking and called the function recursively without helper functions in Lisp. I thought in OCaml it is should work in the same way.
In other languages I used to split the logic into smaller pieces for readability and more convenient use. I was surprised the exception handler should return the integer and I can't just do what I want to do in this case.

Comment: The second variant is exactly what I meant and exactly what I need. This is how functional language should work :)

Comment: `prompt_until_int` could also use an option type where None means quit.